# Basis for a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  **x = (3, −2)**.

Now I am supposed to find a vector that it is basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What should I do first?

Also vector  *(1, 1)*  of the basis should be given in linear combination form.

Comment: Find a vector $y=(a,b)$ so that the pair of vectors $x,y$ is linearly independent. Do you know how to test whether two vectors are linearly independent or not?

Comment: I think so. If the determinant is 0, then it is linearly dependent. Otherwise it is independent, right?

Comment: Yeah, correct. Once you find such a $y$ (there are many of them), you should find scalars (numbers)  $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ so that $(1,1)=\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 y$. This is a system of two equations in two unknowns (the $\lambda$'s).

Comment: So, basically if the vector is (1, 0) then I got det. 2. So it is linearly independent. So for example (1,0) is a correct answer, right?

Comment: Yeah, $(1,0)$ is a correct answer. And then $(1,1)=?(3,-2)+?(1,0)$. Solve for the two questionmarks and you are done. Hint: start from the second coordinate (the second $1$ in $(1,1)$).

Comment: The general method is to recall the [basis extension theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176413/extension-theorem-and-span) which provides an algorithm to extend a linearly independent set of vectors to a basis. Consider the matrix having the initial rows as the set of vectors and the rest of the rows being the standard canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Applying Gauss-Jordan elimination should give you the vectors to include in the extension.

Comment: So is it 1 and 1?  -> As 1*3 - 1*2 = 1 and 1*1 + 1*0 = 1

Comment: Now, first coordinates go with first coordinates. $1=?*3+?*1$ and $1=?*(-2)+?*0$. The second is easier to solve, right?

Comment: Oh, I am so puzzled. I just can't get forward anymore. I got -0,5 but I don't know anymore what I am doing

Answer (score 1):

Show that $x$ and $y:=(1,1)$ are  linearly independent. Then the calculation

$(1,1)= \alpha x+ \beta y$ is very(!) easy !

Comment: 1(3-2) + 1(1+0)

Is that correct in linear combination form?

Honestly I don't know how linear combination form should look like...

Comment: We have the equation $(1,1)= \alpha (3,-2)+ \beta (1,1)$. With only one eye one can see that $\alpha =0$ and $\beta=1$